# Paypal Integration with Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using an ionic native plugin for PayPal payment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/paypal/

My code is:

```
this.payPal.init({   PayPalEnvironmentProduction: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',  
PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX' }).then(() => {  
   this.payPal.prepareToRender('PayPalEnvironmentSandbox', new
   PayPalConfiguration({   })).then(() => {
   let payment = new PayPalPayment('3.33', 'USD', 'Description', 'sale');
   this.payPal.renderSinglePaymentUI(payment).then(() => {}, () => {
});   
}, () => {}, 
() => {});
```

Getting error Can't resolve all parameters for PayPalPayment: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?).

Comment: Code snippet is working fine from here https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/paypal/

Comment: @PareshGami Got the solution. I mistakenly import PayPalPayment, PayPalConfiguration in-app module that causes all this issue. Thank you

Comment: @PareshGami: sir i also using paypal but its not working with INR currecny,i got payment not processible error in the console if i pass INR and $ currency can u help me what i do for fix?

Comment: @Pankaj Dadure: sir are u tried with INR currency?

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap whole code inside a function and call it whenever you need to call.
first you need to  make your sandbox id for testing purpose.And by creating sanbox id you will then need to create an app from which you will get client id. Then insert your client id into  PayPalEnvironmentSandbox.

```
paypalPayment(){
    this.payPal.init({
      PayPalEnvironmentProduction: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
      PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }).then(() => {

      this.payPal.prepareToRender('PayPalEnvironmentSandbox', new PayPalConfiguration({

      })).then(() => {
        let payment = new PayPalPayment('3.33', 'USD', 'Description', 'sale');
        this.payPal.renderSinglePaymentUI(payment).then((success) => {
          console.log(success);
        }, () => {
          // Error or render dialog closed without being successful
          console.log('error paypal')
        });
      }, () => {
        // Error in configuration
        console.log('error configuration paypal')
      });
    }, () => {
      // Error in initialization, maybe PayPal isn't supported or something else
      console.log('error last paypal')
    });
  }
```

Comment: sir i have used above code its not woking for me  if  i pass INR ,i got payment not processbile error in console?

Comment: :means according to country we have to convert currency then assign to USD right?